# How to send an array with jQuery .ajax()

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've got an array like this one :

```
var cars = new Array();
cars['mom'] = "Ford";
cars['dad'] = "Honda";
```

I want to send the array cars via jQuery .ajax() function :

```
     var oDate = new Date();
     $.ajaxSetup({
      cache: false
     });

     $.ajaxSetup({ scriptCharset: "utf-8" ,contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" });

     $.ajax({   
      url: path+'/inc/ajax/cars.php',
      data: {cars:cars},
      cache: false,
      type: "POST",
      success : function(text){
           alert(text);
      }
     });
```

How can I read the array on the server side, with my PHP script ?

Thanks !

Comment: `cars` is not array, it is an object. Javascript has no associative arrays.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299610/how-can-i-send-an-array-to-php-through-ajax

Comment: I found that I only had to create an object at first, not an array.  The rest of my code was good :

    var cars = new Object();
    cars['mom'] = "Ford";
    cars['dad'] = "Honda";

Answer (score 1):

try using php special array `$_POST`

Answer (score 0):

```
$php_array = json_decode($_POST['cars']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $.ajax({   
  url: path+'/inc/ajax/cars.php',
  data: {cars:$(cars).serializeArray()},
  cache: false,
  type: "POST",
  success : function(text){
       alert(text);
  }
 });
```

php

```
$arr = $_POST['cars'];
```