# Write to Session with Post - CakePHP

Tags: ajax, session, cakephp, post, edit

I am trying to post an array of check box ids to an action in my controller.  Here is the script from my index.ctp:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.editSel_dialog').click(function()
{
    var selected = [];
    alert('Edit Selected Has Been Clicked');

    $("#[id*=LocalClocks]").each(function()
        {
        if(false != $(this).is(':checked'))
        {
            selected.push($(this).attr('id').replace('LocalClocks', ''));
        }
    });
    alert(selected);
    /*$.ajax(
    {
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/LocalClocks/editSelected/",
        data: selected,
        traditional: true,
        //contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data){ alert(data); alert('Edit Success');}
    });*/
    $.post('/LocalClocks/editSelected', { "Session" : selected }, function(data){
                   alert(data);
    });
});
</script>
```

I have both an ajax request and a post request.  I was using the ajax until I saw that the post can actually modify a php variable.  The code in the braces `{ "Session" : selected }` should modify the Session variable with the array selected.

I tried using debug on `$this->data`, and `$this->request->data`, and `$_POST`, but they all are empty.

I need help getting the selected array written to a variable or something.  I was thinking of trying to write to `$this->Session` but I am not sure how I would go about doing that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use firebug and see what data is being sent to the server. Try displaying or returning $this->request->params
What does alert() displays? Its an array, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Cake, to get posted values in `$this->request->data`, their names have to be prefixed with `data`:

**Javascript:**

```
$.post('/LocalClocks/editSelected', { "data[Session][selected]" : selected }, function(data){
               alert(data);
});
```

**Controller:**

```
function editSelected()
{
  if($this->request->is('post'))
  {
    if(isset($this->request->data['Session']['selected']))
    {
      $this->Session->write('selected', $this->request->data['Session']['selected']);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help guys. This worked and I am able to post the data successfully. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm wrong, but I think you cannot do that directly from the client side using ajax. Can you share the source your statement regarding you can modify the php variable? I googled for that with no luck, and it will be weird to me being able to modify the PHP session.. it would be really insecure, saying you could use Session Fixation/Injection or other malicious techniques

Edited

For assigning the value on a existing variable you need

Make the ajax call

```
$.post('/LocalClocks/editSelected', { "selected" : selected }, function(data){
                   alert(data);
    });
```

and on your controller you'll have a function like this

```
function editSelected($selected){
$_SESSION["selected"] = $selected;
}
```

and voila

Comment: This is the link to where I got that from: [stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3995907/1438009).  The poster said how the stuff in the braces would change the value of a php variable.  What I have up in the question is my attempt to try and modify the Session, with no luck.  I want to be able to write to a php variable the data in the array, but I don't know how to go about doing that.

Comment: Ohh i see.. the statement there is true, you are ***receiving*** the value on the specified variable, not ***modifying*** an existing one. What you can do is receive that variable and then on PHP assign it to the $_SESSION variable that you want

Comment: Dumb question, but how would I go about doing that.  Would I just create a new variable in my controller's action then assign it to the session?

Comment: I made the changes but now I get this error:
`Missing argument 1 for LocalClocksController::editSelected()`. Any ideas why its not getting the $selected variable?
I think I'm getting closer to getting it working, though.  Thanks.

Comment: On Google Chrome developer tools, on the network tab you can see the actual ajax call you're making. Check if you're sending the value in there

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13080/discussion-between-pollirrata-and-rxc)

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I was missing the `data[][]` in the post call.