# How to send multiple ajax requests?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am new to ajax. I have a function to insert a list of items into sql using a php page, but it only inserts the last item. Please take a look at the code below:

```
function submitItems() {
    ...
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        if (xmlhttp.responseText != "Item Sold")
            alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    for (i=0;i<rows.length;i++) {//a loop to send multiple requests
        xmlhttp.open("POST","submitItem.php?itemid="+itemid,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

The loop sends requests to a php page that does the insertion, but only the last request is processed. If I put an alert() inside the loop, it pops up a window each time, and every item gets inserted, however, it is annoying to keep popping up windows. Any other solutions?

- Or, as the first reply said, I only send one request with an array that stores a list if items. But I don't know how to pass an array as parameter. Can I do this?

  var items = new array();
  items.push(itemid);
  .
  .
  .
  .
  items.push(itemid);
  //then just send it?
  xmlhttp.open("POST","submitItem.php?items="items,true);
  xmlhttp.send();

and then in the php file, shall I do this?

```
$items = $_GET['items'];
```

Comment: Each loop iteration overwrites the ongoing HTTP session that only just began in the previous iteration. Your `alert`s delay that process enough to (sometimes) let the sessions complete.

Comment: I can imagine that. I tried using setTimeout to delay the send request, it does not work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the for loop to generate an array of items (push the different `itemid`s into the array on each iteration) and then make only one AJAX call in which you'll insert all of the items to the database. This way will also optimize your site and save your bandwidth.

Comment: That is what I wanted to do. But don't know how to pass an array as parameter, and how to get it in php. Can you please explain a little bit?

Comment: You can always use JSON (`JSON.stringify(yourAssocArray);`), and then decode it on your AJAX page. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299610/how-can-i-send-an-array-to-php-through-ajax).